# Automatic Formbuilder for Mongoid 2.0 ? Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongoid, formbuilder

Is there a formbuilder for Mongoid 2.0 ? 
Which generates automatically a form from a model.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Why not just use Rails sacffolding?

Comment: Because scaffolding is designed for getting started, not for building a [naked-objects](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Naked_objects) application.

Comment: No, it's because it doesnt add fields automatically to _form.html.erb when you add a new field on a model. 

With MONGOID you don't have to run anymore a new migration for each field you add on a model. It's kind of magic :)

A things that http://web2py.com/ does.

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/mcasimir/document_form

> gem document_form

It's a fork from https://github.com/justinfrench/formtastic i've made, just moved to Mongoid 2.

Model

```
  class Person
    include Mongoid::Document
    include Mongoid::MultiParameterAttributes

    validates_presence_of :name

    field :name
    field :secret,            :private => true
    field :birthday,          :type => Date
    field :department_number, :type => Integer, :range => 1..10

    field :description,       :long => true
  end
```

View

```
    <% document_form_for @object do |f| %>
      <%= f.inputs %>
      <%= f.buttons %>
    <% end %>
```

This is a basic example: here the form builder will render the fields in the same order they are declared, skipping those who have `:private => true`.

If you are not in a hurry and you want something more flexible you can always specify fields ad options using the same syntax as formtastic, something like this:

```
  <% f.inputs do %>
    <%= f.input :title %>
    <%= f.input :published, :label => "This post is published" %>
    <%= f.input :section_id %>
    <%= f.input :image_filename, :hint => "540x300" %>
  <% end %>
```

If you'll decide to give it a  try it i will appreciate any sort of feedback.